# What is this function time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

is this function complexity O(nlogn)?

```
find(n){
    for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
       for(j=1; j<=i; j=j*2) 
           print("*");
    }
 }
```

Comment: yes ......................................................

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228744/value-of-summation-of-logn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity of the inner loop is **O(log2(i))**. The outer loop starts from 0 until n - 1. so the complexity should be **log2(1) + log2(2).... log2(n-1) = log((n-1)!)**.
So the complexity is **O(log2(n!))**.

This is because log(a) + log(b) + log(c)... = log(a*b*c...).
In your case it's log(1) + log(2) + log(3)... + log(n-1) = log(1*2*3*...*(n-1)) = log((n-1)!).

O(log n!) approximates to O(n log n) so your complixity is: **O(n log n)**.

Comment: ...which is equivalent to O(nlogn).

Comment: @ user2357112supportsMonica Yes. I'll add that.